# How to configure Dash to not start in fullscreen?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

I have an older screen with a max resolution of 1024x768.  According to all that I have found, Dash will always open full screen with a height of less than 799.  That makes it very hard to drag things from Dash to the desktop when the desktop cannot be reached when Dash is open.  I need to make Dash use less than the full screen so I can drag things to the desktop. This method (drag to desktop) seems to me to be the only viable way for non-techies to get things on the desktop.

I seem to be able to drag from Dash to the application bar on the left of the screen.  Why can't I drag something from there to the desktop?

Answer (score 2):

If you drag a thing from the dash to the right screen border the dash in Unity 3D (but not in Unity 2D) closes so you can drop that thing on the desktop.

Run

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity form-factor Desktop
```

from the command line if you don't want the Dash to open in full screen mode.

Answer (score 1):

It setting the form-factor doesn't help & if the Dash doesn't close when dragging because you can't reach the edge you can try a little trick.

Grab the icon & start dragging with cursor. Then tap the super button which should close the Dash & expose your desktop where you can then drop the icon.